# can I use the same database for android which I used for ios?

Tags: android, ios, database

I need to know that whether we can use same database or URL for ios as well as android.

For example I am logged in with android so in the section where we use the URL , can we use the same URL for android which we use for ios. Actually I want to make an app for ios and android both.

But I want to make only one database for both that is android and ios.
I have tried using one URL in my login activity which was working on ios..but its not working.can somebody guide me?

Comment: What did you mean by URL? Are you using web services?

Comment: it means where my php file is uploaded and when i run it works

Comment: like the way we used url in java coding for server based app...

Comment: Please include the code you have tried in the question, So others can help.

Comment: code is fine..only the url which is used in ios for same login activity..is not working in android

Comment: Without looking at your URL no one can help you.

Comment: http://.....net/android_api/login.php

Comment: i cannot share the full url ..as its confidential

Comment: Then use fake file and folder names. It looks like your login method is not secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is very possible. It depends on the method youu are using to retrieve/send data to the database. The most popular ways to do the same is use of REST or SOAP to do client-server communication. Both work fine, but you will need to learn about doing the same. I would recomment REST for android since it is the most commonly used and is also easy to understand and use.For Ios i would recommend the AFNetworking library, speed is recommendable. You can download the library using this link:

[https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: like i have given one project which is already done in ios and half in android ..i have been told to use same database which they were using in ios

Comment: Ok... use Rest to do the android requests. You will need to write some scripts to return your db values in Json fromat which you can parse in you android application. You can follow this link and you will get a clear picture of how rest works. Source code is also included. [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/)

Comment: and youre using the same database. No different database is required. You will only be required to host you newly created webservice files in your localhost/server host.